# Remove duplicates, but merge values of duplicate rows

Tags: excel, duplicates, merging-data

For anything with the same commodity code and origin country, I want Excel to add up the value, mass and units columns, leaving just one of each code per country and a total of each of the other rows.

I know it can be done, but I am a bit of a VBA novice so struggling to manipulate suggestions on here to my own sheet, any help would be appreciated!

If it is possible in a pivot table instead, that would be great too, but it needs to be in line with the commodity code to put into a template.

```
 3917390099 - DE - 556.33 
 3917390099 - FR - 38.99
```

not

```
 3917390099
     DE           556.33
     FR           38.99
```

The current data looks like this:

[image: Sample table]

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried sumif() or sumifs() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Pivot-Table.
Adjust the Report Layout to "Show in Tabular Form"
Turn off the Subtotals in the Field Settings.
And if it is neccessary turn on "Repeat All Item Labels"

[image]